# How to apply style from jQuery autocomplete CSS using Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, autocomplete

I am trying to implement **JQuery Autocomplete plugin** using **Django**.
I've been able to wire the thing together and I can actually see the result back in the HTML template.

My problem is that the JQuery Autocomplete CSS doesn't seem to work.
The results I get are **not well-formatted/styled**, **have no background** and **you cannot even select them**.

What is it that I am missing?

I have these three files in my media folder the same folder:

```
autocomplete.js
dimensions.js
autocomplete.css
```

In my html template I have the following function:

```
$(function(){
    setAutoComplete("tags", "tagResults", "/taglookup/?query=");
});
```

My `textfield` looks like this;

```
<input type="text" name="tags" value="">
```

Where do I put the `tagResults` in my HTML template document? Every time I try to introduce a DIV with `id="tagResults"`, JQuery throws an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you point us to a sample page?